# Windows and Ubuntu as dual boot and when partitions should be primary and logical?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have two drives 80GB and 500GB, I want to use 80GB for Windows 8.1 and 500GB drive for ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I read lot of forums/tutorials, but I am confused someone using Primary for Swap, Root and Home and in some tutorials Logical etc etc.

1. Please guide me what is the best way to create partitions in my
   situation?
2. Which partition should be larger, home, root or boot and
   why?

**Note:** I will use Ubuntu for web-development and android-development.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Partitions (from Gabriel)

1. This link helps explain it fairly well. But basically, you should use Primary for both your OS installations. And Swap probably should be a logical drive since you can only have 4 primary drives and there's no real reason to waste on of those spaces for swap.
2. I'm a bit confused by what you mean here. Are you installing separate partitions for each of those folders? There's really no need to do that, you should just install your entire OS on one partition unless you have multiple hard drives or SSDs that aren't large enough to hold a single OS, which most of the time isn't a problem, a little more info would be helpful :)

Comment: LInk suggests 10GB for /, I would use 25GB for / if installing on the larger drive. Then use rest of drive for swap, /home or data partition. And you may want larger shared NTFS data partition also. Windows has to boot from a primary partition and default installs from Windows 7 on, use two, a small Windows only boot and the main install. But you can install Windows to one partition with all boot files inside it. Supposedly main reason for separate Boot partition in Windows was in case you wanted to encrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

you should check out this page :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Partitions

In my case, i've created two partitions :
4 GB Swap Logical
Rest in ext5 Logical

I think it is the best solution
Hope it helped you